# How do I show tracked changes to footnote numbering when I add a new or delete an existing footnote in a document?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I am working with a document that has existing footnotes. I am an editor and need to track the changes that I make to this document. My tracking is turned on, and when I insert a new footnote it tracks the new footnote as added text, but the renumbering of the footnotes that follow the newly-inserted footnote are not tracking the change in renumbering. Example: My new footnote is number 3, and that text shows as blue and underscored, but the existing footnote that follows, which has been renumbered (4), is not showing the tracked change (previously 3, but is now 4).